# Single Page Apps within larger Rails site - one repository or multiple?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a project that is going to have multiple Single Page Apps (eg. a Calendar app, a Budgeting app, etc.) built in AngularJS and using Rails as a back-end. It will also have a large part of the site operating as a normal Rails site - ie. RESTful MVC (eg. `resources :users, :events, ...`).

In the past, our SPAs have lived on a separate server from the back-end, which was delivered by a third-party ([Quickbase](http://www.quickbase.com)) and wasn't under Version Control. Now that we're going to be controlling and developing both the SPAs *and* the RESTful Rails site/back-end the question is how connected/separate should these components be?

- Since the SPA will rely on the back-end for data, does that couple them enough that it should be included as part of the same Git repo?
- Or should they be separated for the sake of maintainability, ease of development, modularity, etc. particularly since they could each be seen as standalone pieces of work?
- Should the SPAs be kept within the Rails directory structure so that they can be served up by Rails and take advantage of the asset pipeline, etc?
- If the SPAs should be kept within the Rails directory structure but should also be separate in version control, how can that be done with them sharing a directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Not a rails developer but just tossing in my two cents.  I do full stack development MySQL -> PHP (Slim PHP framework for routing/RESTfulness), AngularJS.  Currently my workflow is to have all the PHP and AngularJS for a project in one Git repo, really this flows from using Grunt though rather than being a fully conscious decision.  I use Grunt to run the live reload server and added a bit to the base configuration (from yeoman) to handle the PHP portion so that also causes a live-reload which is nice during development.

Regarding code separation, having a RESTful interface for the backend that is completely decoupled from the front-end is your best route, since this leaves you open to completely re-write the front-end without changing the back end (or vice versa).  I'd say anything that breaks this isn't really worth it, if you can't maintain this abstraction you lose the ability to replace one part without rewriting the other.

I would say if you have a piece of the Rails back end code you feel can truly stand on it's own and be used on various projects then perhaps that part should be extracted into it's own repo.

Comment: If the idea is to keep the front/back-end decoupled enough to be able to completely change one without affecting the other, wouldn't it make more sense to keep them in separate repos? Otherwise your history, change log etc. becomes muddled since your front-end's history changes when you change your back end, even though nothing's changed on the front-end.

Comment: If you're working with a team or are concerned with keeping a clean history then maybe it makes sense to have them divided.  The only problem is if you decide to separate them I can't think of a way you can easily configure the Gruntfile.js so it can watch for changes on either part for live reloading (though perhaps this isn't an issue for the server side code).  Being a one man shop so far I'm not heavily concerned with the organization of the repo so long as it's there and I commit often I'm happy with it.